# get attribute value of div in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a table in div and want to get **data-diet_for** of parent div where the class is **row** by jquery

```html
function table2json()
{
  var details = [];
  $('.myTable tbody tr').each(function(i, e) {
    details[i] = {
     diet_for_id: $(this).closest('.row').attr('data-diet_for')
       };
      });
   return(details);
  }
    console.log(table2json);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="card">
  <div class="card-body">
    <div class="card-title toggle d-flex justify-content-between" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#breakfast">
      <strong>Breakfast <span id="breakfast_time"></span></strong>
      <span class="btn btn-sm">
                <i class="fas fa-fw fa-plus"></i>   
            </span>
    </div>
    <div class="row collapse" id="breakfast" data-diet_for="1">
      <div class="col-md-12 table-responsive">
        <table class="table myTable bg-white" style="width:100%" id="breakfast_table">
          <thead class="thead-light">
            <tr>
              <th>Dish</th>
              <th>Type</th>
              <th>Quantity</th>
              <th>Action</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              .....
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

This gives me `undefined` output 
while using `$(this).closest('.card').find('.row').attr('data-diet_for')` gives absolute output
then why first code is not working

Comment: fix the snippet, it is giving exception right now.

Comment: Tell us what part is not working, your code seems to work when add to a snippet

Comment: here `$(this).closest('.row').attr('data-diet_for')` is working fine but not on my PC

Comment: imagine if this question had been asked in 2019, and the code looked more like...

    `const extractDietForIds = () => 
     [...document.querySelectorAll('.myTable tbody tr')]
        .map(tr => ({
          diet_for_id: tr.closest('.row').dataset.dietFor
        }));`

Comment: @EricLease which object is returned by this function?

Comment: [`map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) returns an array.  It's being applied to an array of DOM elements, and returning an array of objects with property `diet_for_id` set to the DOM el's closest's row's `diet-for` data attribute.  This uses the more canonical kebab casing for the data attribute, and `Element.closest` would need to be polyfilled for IE (this is discouraged for performance reasons if you need to support <= IE8).  But what my example code is doing is not the issue here.

Answer (score 0):

it works fine.

```js
var details = [];
$('.myTable tbody tr').each(function(i, e) {
  details[i] = {
    diet_for_id: $(this).closest('.row').attr('data-diet_for')
  };
  
});

console.log(details)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="card">
  <div class="card-body">
    <div class="card-title toggle d-flex justify-content-between" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#breakfast">
      <strong>Breakfast <span id="breakfast_time"></span></strong>
      <span class="btn btn-sm">
    <i class="fas fa-fw fa-plus"></i> 
   </span>
    </div>
    <div class="row collapse" id="breakfast" data-diet_for="1">
      <div class="col-md-12 table-responsive">
        <table class="table myTable bg-white" style="width:100%" id="breakfast_table">
          <thead class="thead-light">
            <tr>
              <th>Dish</th>
              <th>Type</th>
              <th>Quantity</th>
              <th>Action</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              .....
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: But not for me that's why I'm asking this

Comment: but the same code you posted is running here, please add more details.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is working
You should not return a value as you are not inside a `function`.
You can log the value inside a `console.log()` or do something else with it.

```js
var details = [];
$('.myTable tbody tr').each(function(i, e) {
  details[i] = {
    diet_for_id: $(this).closest('.card').find('.row').attr('data-diet_for')
  };
});
console.log(details);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="card">
  <div class="card-body">
    <div class="card-title toggle d-flex justify-content-between" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#breakfast">
      <strong>Breakfast <span id="breakfast_time"></span></strong>
      <span class="btn btn-sm">
    <i class="fas fa-fw fa-plus"></i> 
   </span>
    </div>
    <div class="row collapse" id="breakfast" data-diet_for="1">
      <div class="col-md-12 table-responsive">
        <table class="table myTable bg-white" style="width:100%" id="breakfast_table">
          <thead class="thead-light">
            <tr>
              <th>Dish</th>
              <th>Type</th>
              <th>Quantity</th>
              <th>Action</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              .....
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: but I'm using that jquery in a function  and function return `undefined`